# return 404 from Async Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I have this method in my mvc controller:

```
public ActionResult BlaBla()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();

    // ...
}
```

I want to create an Async version of it. So, I thought to change the code like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> BlaBla()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return new HttpNotFoundResult(); // Compiling error: this line is not working

    // ...
}
```

My question is how to return error codes (404, 500, ...) from my mvc controller, when using `async Task<...>` style?

Comment: As to other error codes, you can use the base `HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode code)` class.  The subclasses of `HttpNotFoundResult` and `HttpNotAuthorizedResult` are shortcuts for the two most common status results (404, 401 respectively).  As to the compile error it's because you aren't returning a task or awaiting any other method call so your compiler isn't autogenerating the Task return type.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: That would be the case without `async` in method signature. However, with `async` the compiler compensates for you, so it's not necessary to actually return a `Task` instance. You will get a compiler warning if you don't actually await anything, but it will still compile.

Comment: What is the actual exception being raised?

Answer (score 6):

There must be a purpose when using an `async` action, right? Usually this purpose is to perform I/O bound operations such as remote TCP/HTTP calls which are exposed through an async service of yours.

In this, a typical controller action looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> BlaBla()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    MyViewModel model = await myService.GetTheModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

In this example, since you already have awaited for an `async` operation inside the method it will compile just fine. If you don't have any `async` operations then there's very little point of having an `async` action. It will do more damage then help. So now the question you should be asking yourself is: Do I really have some async services that can take advantage of I/O completion port to justify my need of using an async action?